# c++ vector losing pointer reference

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime, runtime-error

I should get the same in both lines.. 
what happen I get two different values.. like it was aiming to different positions.. 
I think the error is inside the `d->add(*b)`

the output is

```
  thiago 14333804
  Ph¿├┌ 2816532
```

to describe it better I put the code below

I got a program

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    CClass* c = new CClass();

    BClass* b = c->getNext();

    printf("%s %d \n", b->getValue(), b->getValue());

    DClass* d = new DClass();
    d->add(*b);

    printf("%s %d \n", d->getNext(), d->getNext());

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

the interfaces are below

```
class BClass
{
private:
    char* value;
    bool stale;
public:
    BClass(char* value);
    ~BClass(void);
    char* getValue();
    bool isStale();
};


class CClass
{
private:
    vector<BClass*> list;
public:
    CClass(void);
    ~CClass(void);

    BClass* getNext();
};


class DClass
{
private:
    vector<BClass*> list;
    static bool isStale(BClass* b) { return b->isStale();};
public:
    DClass(void);
    ~DClass(void);
    void add(BClass s);
    char* getNext();
};
```

and the implementation follows

```
//BClass

BClass::BClass(char* value)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->stale = false;
}

BClass::~BClass(void)
{
}

char* BClass::getValue()
{
    return value;
}

bool BClass::isStale()
{
    return stale;
}



//CClass

CClass::CClass(void)
{
    list.push_back(new BClass("thiago"));
    list.push_back(new BClass("bruno"));
    list.push_back(new BClass("carlos"));
}


CClass::~CClass(void)
{
}

BClass* CClass::getNext()
{
    return list.at(0);
}

//DClass

DClass::DClass(void)
{
}

DClass::~DClass(void)
{
}

void DClass::add( BClass s )
{
    list.push_back(&s);
}

char* DClass::getNext()
{
    BClass* b = list.at(0);

    return b->getValue();
}
```

Comment: The pointer address will be different, but the address of what the pointer is pointing to can be the same

Comment: you pass an object to add by copy and not by pointer. That is way you get an address of a temporary object that is on the stack and its scope is inside add() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass in an instance of class `B` into `D::add()` function you *create a deep copy* of the object and that copy is what is put on stack. Later on you use the *address of that copy* to push it into list. Once the function is done this automatic variable goes out of scope thus the *pointer* you used to put into list is no longer valid.

To fix change your interface to avoid deep copies as follows:

```
void DClass::add( BClass * s )
{
    list.push_back(s);
}
```

*Step-by-step of what your code is doing*

1. `BClass* b = c->getNext();` // you get the address of the first element from the list (created in constructor) and assign it to `b`
2. `d->add(*b);` // the *b will dereference the object pointed to by `b` and put it onto stack in preparation to the call to `add()`
3. `void DClass::add( BClass s ){` // the deep copy of a dereferenced object is put into this function's stack frame
4. `list.push_back(&s);` // an address of that *temporary* copy of the original object is being used to be added to your list
5. `}` // this is where the fun happens - once the function is done it will unwind the stack back up and the memory, previously occupied by that temp copy, will be re-used for other purposes. In your case - it will be used to pass parameters to functions `d->getNext()` (there's always a hidden *this* parameter to non-static member functions) and later to the `printf()` function. Remember - your previous pointer to that temp copy is still pointing to the stack, but it's now occupied by different data, causing you to see corruption

General rule of thumb - never use pointers to temp objects ;-)

Comment: @YePhlicK isnt there anyway for me to guarantee that the address of s to be always valid even afters this function scope?

Comment: Only if the address is in heap OR if you are doing some *really* funky hacking and ensuring that the stack frame is not being re-used (that's an extremely non-trivial task and nobody in their right mind should ever think of doing it, except for very special applications like anti-debugging mesures)

Answer (score 1):

in the `DClass::add` function, `BClass s` is a local variable.

```
void DClass::add( BClass s )
{
    list.push_back(&s);
}
```

When you call `d->add(*b);`, you're passing a `BClass` by value, meaning you're creating a copy of it, and the address of that copy is not the same address of the original.

`s` will go out of scope as soon as the function returns, and the pointer to it will be invalid. So storing that pointer is no good to you, since dereferencing it would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: isnt there anyway for me to guarantee that the address of `s` to be always valid even afters this function scope?

Comment: as far as I know there's nothing you can do to avoid `s` itself from going out of scope. You could write a constructor that copies that object and create a `new BClass(s)`, and store that pointer, but I think you'd want to go with the other solution, simply change `add (BClass s)` to `add(BClass* s)` and passing the pointer instead of making a copy.